# Isn't creating a Flex skin by copying code a Bad Thing?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, mxml, skin

I've created a number of skins for various components recently.  Some of these were for Spark components and the default behavior of Flash Builder is to take the source code of the original skin and copy into your skin as a starting point.

Normally, I am 90% ok with the original skin, I just want to tweak or add one little thing.  It seems to me that duplicating 3 pages of source code to do this is a bad idea.  What do I do when I upgrade Flex SDKs?  Do I have to go back through the source of all these original skins and (re)compare?  This sounds like a disaster.

Is there a way I can create a new skin in MXML that inherits from the old skin?  Can I do this via ActionScript?

Comment: Did find a good article on the subject - http://blog.paveljacko.com/?p=29

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade your Flex SDK I don't think there should be any modification in the skinParts of components. Anyway if there were, you would have a compilation error if one of your implemented skinparts is not of the right type or if you miss a required skinPart. So I wouldn't worry if I were you :)

Another tip would be to use as much as possible CSS styling to avoid this kind of problems.

And no, I don't think you can inherit from a skin and modify its elements (but I'd be glad to be proved wrong).

Comment: I hear you on the CSS...already doing as much there as I can.